# Integer linear programming + python + ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, linear-programming

I would like to solve an integer linear programming problem in python for the first time. After searching online I was pointed to lp_solve but I can't see how to get the python bindings installed in ubuntu.  I have also had gurobi and cplex recommended but they are no open source. Is there a nice and simple way to set up an integer linear programming problem and have it solved in python using only free software?

Answer (score 1):

I'm attending course on linear programming at the moment, recommended module for programming assignments was [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org).

I've actually found that I like [PuLP module](https://code.google.com/p/pulp-or/) much more.
It's really nice module, give it a try.

Comment: Does it do integer linear programming?

Comment: @Anush yes, you can set every variable as LpInteger - http://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html#problem-description

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at SCIP, see http://scip.zib.de/ and the Python interface
http://code.google.com/p/python-zibopt/, just look at the ZIB licence first.

If Academic licence is an option, you can get Cplex, Gurobi, Xpress and some others as well. I think GLPK may be an option if really free is the only option.

IMO, SCIP is fantastic for advanced prototyping, but obviosly works fine for simpler things like just setting up the ILP and solving it. Observe that SCIP can be wired with the most popular commercial alternatives as well for better performance.

Comment: Thank you. I am attempting to install python-zibopt following https://code.google.com/p/python-zibopt/wiki/Installation . It is a long and painful process so far. I tried pip install python-zibopt as well but it fails with src/ext/python_zibopt.h:10:34: fatal error: blockmemshell/memory.h: No such file or directory .

Comment: @Anush: this means your C_INCLUDE_PATH is not set correctly. (I'm stuck as well, but later in the process.)

Comment: With our latest release of SCIP we also shipped a (very basic) own python interface using cython. You should give it a try. Extending the interface to support more functions should be straightforward.